# chart.js-plugin-annotations multiple horizontal lines in one chart

Tags: javascript, annotations, chart.js

I am using chart.js 2.6 and chart.js-plugin-annotations 0.5.5 to create a graph.

I need to add 3 horizontal lines using annotations on the same graph but only the last one in the list is drawn. If I switch the placement of the annotations the last one is still drawn so the code for each annotation seems to works, but only the last one shows.

```
 annotation: {
   drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
     annotations: [{
                        id: 'hline1',
                        type: 'line',
                        mode: 'horizontal',
                        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                        value: speedAverage,
                        borderColor: 'green',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }],
                    annotations: [{
                        id: 'hline3',
                        type: 'line',
                        mode: 'horizontal',
                        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                        value: speedToleranceMin,
                        borderColor: 'red',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        label: {
                            backgroundColor: "red",
                            content: "Min Value",
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }],
                    annotations: [{
                        id: 'hline2',
                        type: 'line',
                        mode: 'horizontal',
                        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                        value: speedToleranceMax,
                        borderColor: 'red',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        label: {
                            backgroundColor: "red",
                            content: "Max Value",
                            enabled: true
                        }
            }]
   }
```

whats wrong here?
Expected result is to see all 3 lines not just 1 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the plugin incorrectly. Correct way should be ...

```
annotation: {
   drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
   annotations: [{
      id: 'hline1',
      type: 'line',
      mode: 'horizontal',
      scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
      value: speedAverage,
      borderColor: 'green',
      borderWidth: 1
   }, {
      id: 'hline3',
      type: 'line',
      mode: 'horizontal',
      scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
      value: speedToleranceMin,
      borderColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: 1,
      label: {
         backgroundColor: "red",
         content: "Min Value",
         enabled: true
      }
   }, {
      id: 'hline2',
      type: 'line',
      mode: 'horizontal',
      scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
      value: speedToleranceMax,
      borderColor: 'red',
      borderWidth: 1,
      label: {
         backgroundColor: "red",
         content: "Max Value",
         enabled: true
      }
   }]
}
```

Comment: I assumed I was using it wrongly, but I started using javascript a few weeks ago and the documentation is still a bit hard for me to understand sometimes.
Solutions works perfectly.